# Restore postgres Backup Data in DB (DB name contain spaces) using Postgres JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

We are trying to restore backup file to postgres DB with the DB name contain spaces. Ex: "abbb   abc  ", "dqweqwe fdf fsdf   ",...
But after restore the data not showing in that DB name (checked by pgAdmin tool).
Here are our backup restore java commands:

```
   String host = "localhost";
   String port = "5432";
   String databaseName = "abc    abc    "; 
   String user = "postgres";
   String backupFilePath= "C:\Users\Sun\Desktop\backup.backup";

   final String RESTORE_COMMAND = "pg_restore -c -h %s -p %s -U %s -d %s -v %s";
   String cmd = String.format(RESTORE_COMMAND, host, port, user, databaseName, backupFilePath);
   // Execute commands by  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd )
   excuteCommand(cmd);
```

We tried to with some escapses string like "" or '' or [] or even replace spaces in databaseName by \ but it haven't worked yet.
Are these any suggests in our case ? Please help, thank so much.

Comment: You might want to consider calling `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String[])` with a correctly populated array of strings instead of `Runtime.exec(String)`

Comment: Yes, the command to using for execute restore was guaranteed correctly

Answer (score 0):

Try to quote your database name as follow: `'"databasename"'`
So the java variable should look this way:

```java
   String databaseName = "'\"abc    abc\"'";
```

Comment: I have just tried your comment but it did not work. Do you have more any suggest for me? thanks

Comment: Can you execute sql command: `select * from pg_catalog.pg_database;` or `\l+` from psql client? I am sure this database exists but UI tool can't show it

Comment: Yes, if i execute this command in window command line, by using quotes \", to wrap database name it work perfectly, but it not work with java, i dont know how :(

Comment: Why are you using and single quotes and double quotes? Choose one

Comment: I tried either single quotes or double quotes or combine both of them but did not work @Mark Rotteveel